# Failed to fill a dictionary when iterating with a splited tuple /w Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Some help will appreciated cause I don't understand what is append when I try to fill a dictionnary by spliting terms from a tuple.

Here the tuple :

```
for i in tpl_walllg:
    print(i)

(11001, 43.27)
(11003, 5.13)
(11004, 23.62)
(11005, 5.22)
```

When I iterate on it, by spliting terms and put in form, it works :

```
for i in tpl_walllg:
    print("Wall {id} / {lg}m".format(id=i[0], lg=i[1]))

Wall 11001 / 43.27m
Wall 11003 / 5.13m
Wall 11004 / 23.62m
Wall 11005 / 5.22m
```

So I decided to use this method to fill a pre-shaped dictionary with that, first term of the tuple is the 'root' key of the dict and the second, the value affected.

```
for i in tpl_walllg:
    wm[i[0]]['propriétés']['géo']['lg'] = i[1]
```

The iteration works, but why the value is the same (the last wall) ? Take a look :

```
for i in tpl_walllg:
    print(wm[i[0]]['propriétés']['géo']['lg'])

5.22
5.22
5.22
5.22
```

And put in form :

```
for i in tab_wallID:
    print('The wall n°{id} is {lg}m long'.format(id=i, lg=wm[i]['propriétés']['géo']['lg']))

The wall n°11001 is 5.22m long
The wall n°11003 is 5.22m long
The wall n°11004 is 5.22m long
The wall n°11005 is 5.22m long
```

Here tab_wallID is just a list of wallID.

Below, the dictonary building :

```
wm = {}  # Création d'un dictionnaire (wm : wall matrix)

dic_prop = {'géo': {'ep': float(),  # wall tickness
                    'lg': float(),  # wall lenght
                    'ht': float()  # wall height
                    },
            'méca': {'fck': int(),
                     # characteristic compressive strength of concrete
                     'fyk': int()
                     # characteristic yield strength of reinforcement
                     },
            'spatiale': {}  # not used yet
            } 


for i in tab_wallID:
    wm[i] = {'propriétés': dic_prop,
             'torseurs': dic_comb
             }
```

Comment: Can you include the code for how you preshaped the dictionary?

Comment: Following your request, I added its creation (only the 'propriétés' branch where 'lg' is)

Comment: In your dictionary building stage where you define wm[i] with the iterator i in `tab_wallID`, are you sure you want to make the wm key as a tuple?

Comment: `tab_wallID` is a list of integer (wall ID). I created some tuples like `tpl_walllg` to link the wall long with its ID, etc. I decided to create some intermediate tuples to keep some traceability in my process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because when you build your `wm` dictionary, you are pointing to the same `dic_prop` object. That's why when looping, the same property dictionary gets updated consecutively with every new `i[1]`.

One way around it would be to change the way you construct `wn` to a dictionary literal, something like:

```
for i in tab_wallID:
    wm[i] = {'propriétés': {'géo': {'lg': float()}}}
```

**Edit:**

Another way could be to copy `dict_prop` dictionary every time it's assigned to a key, for example:

```
import copy

for i in tab_wallID:
    wm[i] = {'propriétés': copy.deepcopy(dic_prop)}
```

Comment: I think I understood.
In your opinions, can any other method be used to keep a construction by stages in this spirit with external dictionaries (= previously declared) ?